# SQL server, difference two tables and mix together

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have two tables: tbMetals and tbSells

tbMetals

```
mId - name   - cost
1   - Iron   - 100
2   - Steel  - 200
3   - Copper - 300
4   - Zinc   - 150
```

tbSells

```
CustomerId - mId - SellDate - weight
100        - 1   - 2017/1/1 - 1.2
100        - 2   - 2017/1/2 - 3.5
111        - 1   - 2017/3/3 - 2.1
```

I need like this output for ClientId=100

```
mId - SellDate - weight
1   - 2017/1/1 - 1.2
2   - 2017/1/2 - 3.5
3   - NULL     - NULL
4   - NULL     - NULL
```

Comment: Learn about [`OUTER JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: This type of question has been asked 10,000 times over here. Please do some research before posting

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple left join.

```
select
    m.mId
    ,s.SellDate
    ,s.weight
from
    tbMetals m
left join
    tbSells s on
    s.mId = m.mId
    and s.ClientId = 100   --optional, if you really want it.
```